# Javascript is not working after pagination

Tags: javascript, ajax, pagination

i have a problem with my javascript on a pagination page (ajax). The first page is working well, but if i click on the "page 2" the javascript is not loading.

Here is a snipped of my js code which i add into the footer.php :

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $('#mp-id-2130725945 div[data-label="Yes"] .mp-choice-label').click(function() {...}
 }
```

do I have to use a special code for pagination pages? I thought that the js will be reloaded?

thanks!

Comment: Try showing **all** relevant code.

Comment: Best guess: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: And no, if the pagination works with Ajax, it won't reload scripts.

Comment: thanks JJJ, i tried it with this code but i make something wrong. Possible that you quickly check this?  jQuery(document).ready(function($){


         

                $('#mp-id-2130725945 div[data-label="Yes"] .mp-choice-label').on('click', '#mp-id-2130725945 div[data-label="Yes"] .mp-choice-label', function(){
                      $("#mp-id-3372138702").css("display","block");
                });

Comment: It's supposed to be `$(document).on('click','#mp-id-2130725945 div[data-label="Yes"] .mp-choice-label')`. Repeating the selector isn't going to work.

Comment: thanks! Question: do i add this into the document.ready function?  jQuery(document).ready(function($){


            $(document).on('click','#mp-id-2130725945 div[data-label="Yes"] .mp-choice-label'){
                
                  $("#mp-id-7740120141").css("display","block");

            };

         
            $('#mp-id-5597852198 div[data-label="Yes"] .mp-choice-label').click(function() {
                     $("#mp-id-9153215455").css("display","block");
            });